# PHP: Read custom meta-data from converted .mobi file

Tags: php, epub, kindlegen

So i made a tool in PHP that adds a custom meta-data to a .epub-file.

After that i used the kindlegen-tool to convert my .epub to a .mobi.

Now im looking for some code-snippets or samples to read my .mobi-file, in detail:
I want to read my custom meta-data from that .mobi-file.

Answer (score 0):

mobi files are more or less XHTML packaged and zipped files like ePubs.

So you can simply change the .mobi file extension to .zip, extract the content and look inside.